# DC.js numberDisplay with crossfilter get total records

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to understand how to use crossfilter with dc.js. I have the following data and I would just like to start by populating a numberDisplay with the total number of objects within the data. Then secondly populating how many records there are for bills losses.

```
var data = [
  {
    "team": "bills",
    "location": "home",
    "outcome": "loss"
  },
  {
    "team": "dolphins",
    "location": "away",
    "outcome": "loss"
  },
  {
    "team": "jets",
    "location": "home",
    "outcome": "loss"
  },
  {
    "team": "jets",
    "location": "home",
    "outcome": "win"
  },
  {
    "team": "dolphins",
    "location": "home",
    "outcome": "loss"
  },
  {
    "team": "dolphins",
    "location": "away",
    "outcome": "win"
  },
  {
    "team": "dolphins",
    "location": "home",
    "outcome": "win"
  },
  {
    "team": "dolphins",
    "location": "away",
    "outcome": "loss"
  }
]
```

DC.JS numberDisplay takes a group but I have not been able to figure out how to simply count the number of records to start with.

```
var cf = crossfilter(data);
var team = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d.team })
var teams = team.group().reduceCount();
```

this seems to only return the value for the first key? reduceSum() and groupAll() haven't worked either.

```
var numberDisplayElem = dc.numberDisplay("#number-display-elem");
    numberDisplayElem
        .group(teams);
```

Basically just trying to get the total to populate the numberDisplay, and then a single numberBack of filtered values like total bills losses, etc. Having trouble getting started. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinary crossfilter group has multiple bins based on the key function.

If you want to count all the records without binning them, try using a [groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll) instead:

```
var numRecords = cf.groupAll();
numberDisplayElem
  .group(numRecords)
  .valueAccessor(x => x);
```

Comment: Thanks very much...I was simply missing the valueAccessor piece and getting NaN when I tried using it. Sorry for the poor explanation, I simply meant I am now interested in filtering for total count with all records that has team prop of "Bills", then next would be "Bills" with an outcome of losses, etc. As I said I am just getting started

Comment: Ah, failed to parse that, got it now. Yes it's weird that you have to specify the `valueAccessor` when this is the most common case. `crossfilter.groupAll` will observe all filters, so once you start adding charts for teams, win/loss, those will affect `numRecords` and the number display.